# Update string in file in web app deployed on microsoft Azure PAAS

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, paas

I have file deployed in app service. I want update string **stringToReplace** in file.

<> **stringToReplace** <>

1. Dont want to redeployment
2. Want to update file string using powershell(not Manually)

Comment: If it is something like config file, you can try using kudu to update the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we have no way to do that **directly** with powershell. You could give [your idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) to Azure WebApp team.

> - Dont want to redeployment
> - Want to update file string using powershell(not Manually)

Based on my experience, I recommond that you could use the Azure Kudu [VFS API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to get the file content and replace the string that you want and put it with new content to file on the Azure. Then you will no need to redeploy the azure webapp, just update the single file that you want..

```
GET /api/vfs/{path}
Gets a file at path

PUT /api/vfs/{path}
Puts a file at path.
```

How to use the Azure Kudu Rest API with powershell you could refer to this [blog](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2017/03/03/copy-files-to-azure-web-app-with-powershell-and-kudu-api).The following is the snippet code from the blog

**Get API authorisation:**

```
function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName){

    $publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName

    return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}
```

**Upload a single file**

```
function Upload-FileToWebApp($kuduApiAuthorisationToken, $webAppName, $fileName, $localPath ){

    $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/app/resources/$fileName"

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                        -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                        -Method PUT `
                        -InFile $localPath `
                        -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
}
```